# How to read from a text file and add that data to a graph in c++

Tags: c++, streamreader

I have a text file that has 256 pairs of data. I need to take those pairs and put them into the vectors for the graph. I am know how to do this in C# but I am new to C++. The format of the text file is

```
125, 151
124, 176
ect...
```

I need it to come into the vectors for the graph in the format of graph[n][m], where n = 256 and m=256. So I would read through the file and would mark 1 on the number that corresponds with the L/R Pair.
So for example 125, 151. I would go to the 125th line and I would mark the 151'st 0 to be 1.

```
[n][m]{{0,0,0... 1(//176th 0),0,0,0...}, //124th line
{0,0,0... 1(//151st 0),0,0,0...}, //125th line
ect.
```

Does C++ have anything like the streamreader method out of C#?

Here is a sample of the vectors for a 7x7 max flow problem.

```
int graph[V][V] = { {0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                      };
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "graph"?

Comment: Ultimately it will be going into a Bipartite Graph. Therefore graph is a function I created earlier in the program. I'm trying to avoid typing in 256 different pairs manually.

Comment: Isn't that n=256, m=2?

Comment: No n and m should represent the max size of the the set. Each set is going to have 256 options.

Comment: I don't know C#, but it sounds as if you misunderstand how arrays work in C++. I recommend that you start with some simpler exercises.

Comment: You want to 1) create a 2-dimensional container full of zeroes, 2) read numbers from a text file, and 3) change some of elements in the container according to the numbers. All these things can be done in C++, but I advise you to tackle them separately before you try to combine them. It sounds as if you should be searching for "C++ stream I/O".

Comment: @Beta That is exactly what I want to do. I know I can do it with Streamreader from the io library in C#

Answer (score 0):

as @Beta said in the comments under your question, you want to
1) create a 2-dimensional container full of zeroes
2) read numbers from a text file
3) change some of elements in the container according to the numbers.

So here some tips:
1- For creating a 2D container:

```
 auto a = new int[100, 100]{0};
```

in this code you made an array of `int`s which is full of zeros. the elements that were not initialized in `{ }` part, would set to default value. which is zero for int.

2- reading numbers from a text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

and in your code:

```
int x , y;
ifstream fin("yourFile.txt");
fin >> x >> y; //Jusy like "cin"
//Do what you want
//and after that close the stream
fin.close();
```

3- change some of elements in the container according to the numbers:
Simply do it like this:

```
a[i,i] = x;
```