# How to Import an edge list from a text file into a bipartite graph using C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a edge list of 256 inputs/outputs. I need to import these list values into a bipartite graph. I'm new with C++ and don't know where to start. I ultimately need to parse through this list and go to the input line which would be the "row" and the output value which would be the "column" and set that value to 1 (for true). Hope this makes sense.

Sample text file data:

```
192, 16
120, 134
256, 87
122, 167
142, 97
157, 130
245, 232
223, 63
```

Here is my program

```
// A C++ program to find maximal Bipartite matching.
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// M is number of inputs and N is number of outputs
#define M 256
#define N 256

// A DFS based recursive function that returns true if a
// matching for vertex u is possible
bool bpm(bool bpGraph[M][N], int u, bool seen[], int matchR[])
{
    // Try every output one by one
    for (int v = 0; v < N; v++)
    {
        // If input u is connected to output v and v is
        // not already connected to
        if (bpGraph[u][v] && !seen[v])
        {
            seen[v] = true; // Mark v as connected

            // If output 'v' is not assigned to an input OR
            // previously assigned input for output v (which is matchR[v]) 
            // has an alternate output available. 
            // Since v is marked as visited in the above line, matchR[v] 
            // in the following recursive call will not get output'v' again
            if (matchR[v] < 0 || bpm(bpGraph, matchR[v], seen, matchR))
            {
                matchR[v] = u;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Returns maximum number of matching from M to N
int maxBPM(bool bpGraph[M][N])
{
    // An array to keep track of the Inputs assigned to
    // Outputs. The value of matchR[i] is the Input number
    // assigned to input i, the value -1 indicates nothing is
    // assigned.
    int matchR[N];

    // Initially all outputs are available
    memset(matchR, -1, sizeof(matchR));

    int result = 0; // Count of matches
    for (int u = 0; u < M; u++)
    {
        // Mark all Inputs as not connected for next output.
        bool seen[N];
        memset(seen, 0, sizeof(seen));

        // Find if the input'u' can connect to an output
        if (bpm(bpGraph, u, seen, matchR))
            result++;
    }
    return result;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    // Let us create a bpGraph shown in the above example



    bool bpGraph[M][N] = {};

    cout << "Maximum number networks "
         << maxBPM(bpGraph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should better reformulate your question to just parsing the input, and show what (in parsing!) you have tried and why your approach did not work, otherwise the questions seems to be offtopic. Just asking "how to write this" would hardly get you any answers. Therefore, as the question is currently written, I vote to close it.

Comment: Also please tell us how you want to represent a graph. Is it an adjacency list or matrix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read from a text file and add that data to a graph in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814392/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-and-add-that-data-to-a-graph-in-c)

Comment: You asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814392/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-and-add-that-data-to-a-graph-in-c) 14 hours ago. Now it appears that you have implemented the responses -- in part -- and want... something? You're new to C++ and don't know where to start? I advise you to start with simpler exercises. This is a real-world problem and you need a solution? Your profile says you're some kind of IT manager in a large company, so give it to a developer.

Comment: @Beta this is a homework problem I am working through. I don't want it solved just ideas on how to work through it. Right now I am hung up on how to pull data into the graph function. Yes I am new to C++, I'm well versed in C#/Java but unfortunately I have to use C++.

Thanks!